# Using ML inequality Show that the fallowing relation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

$$\left|\int_{\gamma (t)} e^{iz^2} \ dz \right| ≤ \frac{\pi (e-1)}{4e}$$, Where $$\gamma (t)=e^{it},t\in[0,\pi/4]$$

This is question in Complex Analysis by Ponnusamy Page_128 ,I tried it but unable to get this
My Attempt: $L=\pi/4$ and $M=\max_{t\in[0,\pi/4]}|e^{i{\gamma (t)}^2}|=1$

Which gives $\pi/4$ instead of $\frac{\pi (e-1)}{4e}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\sin x$ is a concave function for $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, we get the inequality
$$\sin x\geq \frac{2}{\pi}x,\quad 0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
We're going to use this inequality applied to $x=2t$ in the following calculation:
$$\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{\gamma(t)}e^{iz^2}\; dz\right|&\leq \int_{\gamma(t)}\left|e^{iz^2}\right|\; |dz|\qquad\text{(by the $M$-$L$ inequality)}\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{-\sin 2t}\; dt\\
&\leq\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{-(4/\pi)t}\; dt\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\left(1-e^{-(4/\pi)(\pi/4)}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi(e-1)}{4e}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: you integrated that one but why we are not getting the result to this way 
$\max_{t\in[0,\pi/4]}|e^{i{\gamma (t)}^2}|=\max_{t\in[0,\pi/4]}|e^{-\sin 2t}|=1$

Comment: Because the maximum is much larger than the average value of the function, so it is too high of a bound. You have to integrate if you want to do better than $\pi/4$.

Comment: It means , $\left|\int_{\gamma (t)} e^{iz^2} \ dz \right| ≤ \pi /4$ is not wrong but it is not a good result.?

Comment: Exactly. Because the result they want is to show that the integral is even smaller than $\pi/4$, by another $\pi/(4e)$.